# Image background repeats on big display monitors

Tags: css

As you can see in the screenshot the background image repeats when displayed in a big monitor:

[image]

Does anyone suggest any workaround for this?

(And sample CSS code if possible)

Live site: http://www.carleighmac.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious answer is to use:

```
#featured-area {
    /* other CSS unchanged */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Currently Chrome's Web Inspector tool shows the background-property rules defined as:

```
background: url(/themes/sunrise/img/nav/slider-background-baby.jpg) repeat-x top center;
```

If you replace '`repeat-x` with the above `no-repeat` this would be the shorthand version of the above.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want it to repeat and want to show it in full-width (if your image is smaller than monitor screen), you can use this css.

More options are here http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

```
#yourElementID {
  float:left;
  width:100%;
  height:300px; 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat top center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your image is not a fit for the display, then you'll have to repeat it or center it or fit(zoom and crop) it.

1. For centering, its quite easy to do with only CSS. Use the non-repeat option as mentioned in other answers. But in my opinion, this may look a little ugly.
2. For repeat, you already have it.
3. Now as far as fit is concerned, you can refer to a nice article here: http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Answer (score 0):

If you use the background shorthand property, then it will be:

```
background: url("/themes/sunrise/img/nav/slider-background-baby.jpg") no-repeat center top;
```

Details *[here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp)*.